desktop-save-mode does not restore org-agenda buffers when running Emacs as daemon
I run Emacs as daemon and have the following to save/restore my buffers/frames. It works fine (need to save-buffers-kill-emacs instead of C-x C-c to get the buffers to be saved then buffers are restored on emacsclient -c after the daemon starts). However, for org-agenda buffers (e.g. a buffer showing org agenda for the current week/day, not to be confused with org agenda files which restore fine), they are instead replaced with either a scratch buffer or a seemingly random org agenda file.
    (use-package desktop
      (setq desktop-base-file-name "emacs.desktop")
      (setq desktop-path '("~/.cache/emacs"))
      (setq desktop-load-locked-desktop t)
      (setq desktop-dirname "~/.cache/emacs")
      (setq desktop-auto-save-timer nil)
      (setq desktop-auto-save-timeout 0)
      (setq desktop-save t)
    
      (defun my-restore-desktop-add-save-hook ()
        (unless desktop-save-mode
          (add-hook 'server-done-hook #'(lambda ()
                                          (desktop-save "~/.cache/emacs")))
          (desktop-save-mode 1)
          (desktop-read)))
    
      (add-hook 'server-after-make-frame-hook 'my-restore-desktop-add-save-hook))


You need to customize desktop-buffer-mode-handlers to save org-agenda-mode  buffers.
